# Possible way to get slug but still getting id in php

Tags: php

My problem is I successfully put slug on URL but I create a function the show all all the child post under my parent post.

```
Parent Blog Post
    - Child post 1
    - Child post 2
```

Database

```
Child post table
--------------------------------
id |   parent_id  |  title
--------------------------------
1  |   1          |  child post
--------------------------------
```

If you see my table is parent id but when I change my URL into slug I can't get the id because is already change the URL by slug. Is there a possible way to get id even I change the URL into slug?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, store url slug in table. e.g.

```
Child post table
-------------------------------------------------
id |   parent_id  |  title             | slug
-------------------------------------------------
1  |   1          |  child post        | child-post
2  |   1          |  new child post    | new-child-post
```

Now, you can get `parent_id` using slug.

Comment: I understand this what I want to do is when I view the parent post the child post of that parent post will show up?

Parent Post - (I view this child post will show up)
    - Child Post 1
    - Child Post 2 
How can i query the child post even my url is not id is already slug
localhost/parent-post-slug/

Comment: I'm not viewing child post, I'm viewing parent post which child post will display too

Comment: You can use subquery like ||||| select * from post where parent_id = (select parent_id from post where slug='$parent_slug') ||||

Answer (score 0):

How to select query both parent post and child post and my URL is slug and not ID?

Parent Post

- Child Post 1
- Child Post 2

Well if I have site.com/id?=1 is easy to call but I changed the URL into slug so the URL now is site.com/slug/ so when I call get id it won't appear because my URL slug not id? What is the best solution for this?